# A question about surface term of ghost fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, ghosts

(skip disclaimer)

Hi, I have a question in Polchinski's string theory vol I p 90, after introducing the ghost fields $b_{ab}$ and $c^a$, it is claimed

> The equations of motion then provide a boundary condition on $b_{ab}$. They have a surface term
>   $$ \int_{\partial M} ds n^a b_{ab} \delta c^b=0 \tag{3.3.28}$$

I simply don't know where does it comes from. There are some boundary condition
$n_a c^a=0 (3.3.26)$ but with different indices. How to see Eq. (3.3.28) holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer :

I think that the problem, in Polchinski book, is that the terms $g^{z \bar z} (=2)$, are systematically non explicitely written, that is, instead of : 
$\frac{1}{4 \pi}g^{z \bar z}$, Polchinkski write : $\frac{1}{2 \pi}$

So, for instance, the correct expression in $(3.3.24)$ is :

$$ S = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \int d^2z (g^{\bar z z}b_{zz} \partial_\bar z c^z + g^{z \bar z }b_{\bar z \bar z} \partial_z c^\bar z)$$

Now, because $b_{z \bar z}=0$, because $b$ is traceless,and $g^{zz}=g^{\bar z \bar z}=0$ ,this is really an invariant, that is :

$$ S = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \int d^2z (g^{ i j}b_{jk} \partial_ i c^k)$$, 
where ($i,j = z, \bar z$)

Now, an invariant is an invariant, so you could write it with ($i,j = \sigma^1, \sigma^2$), if, you want, so, with Polchinski notations :

$$ S = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int d^2 \sigma (g^{ ca}b_{ab} \partial_c c^b)$$,

Then the boundary term appears as :

$$\delta B \sim \int ds~ g^{ ca} n_c ~b_{ab}  ~\delta c^b = \int ds ~  n^a ~b_{ab}  ~\delta c^b $$

Comment: Thank you very much! How do you know $b_{z\bar{z}}=0$?

Comment: $b^{z \bar z} =\partial_1 z ~\partial_1 \bar z b^{11} + \partial_1 z ~\partial_2 \bar z b^{12} + \partial_2 z ~\partial_1 \bar z b^{21} + \partial_2 z ~\partial_2 \bar z b^{22} = \frac{1}{4} (b^{11} + i b^{12} - i b^{21} + b^{22})$. 

$b$ is traceless and symmetric, so, in the euclidean metric $g_{ab}$, this means that : 
$b_{12}= b_{21}$ and $b^{11} + b^{22} = 0$. So, finally , $b^{z \bar z} = 0$. With an analog demonstration, we get $b^{\bar z z } = 0$.

Comment: To get $b_{z \bar z}$ or $b_{ \bar z z}$, we simply apply the metric $g_{z \bar z}$ $2$ times to the quantities $b^{z \bar z},b^{\bar z z } $. So $b_{z \bar z}$ and $b_{ \bar z z}$ are zero too;

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this term, you have to apply partial integration with respect to one of the coordinates to the action. This leaves you with one integral over two dimensions (with the derivative switched from $c$ to $b$) and an integral over one dimension. If you now vary the second term with respect to $c$ and you acquire Eq. 3.3.28.

Comment: Sorry, which action in "to the action" do you mean?

Comment: The (gauge-fixed) action of the ghost fields, given by Eq. 3.3.24.

Comment: In (3.3.28), there is a term $\int_{\partial M} ds n^z b_{z \bar{z}} \delta c^{\bar{z}}$ does not come from (3.3.24)(?), why it does not affect the validity of (3.3.28)?

Comment: 3.3.28 follows from 3.3.24 by partial integration and the variational principle, as I have already explained.

Comment: Sorry, from variation of $z$ in (3.3.24), after integrating the total derivative of $z$ and $\bar{z}$ from the integration by parts, I got $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int dz \int_{\partial \bar{z} } b_{zz} \delta c_z + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int d\bar{z} \int_{\partial z }  b_{\bar{z} \bar{z}} \delta  c^{\bar{z}}$$, not recover (3.3.28)...

Comment: Something is wrong in your notation, you can't have two  integral signs and only one infinitesimal element $dz$.

Comment: I mean $$\delta S_g = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int d^2 z b_{zz} \partial_{\bar{z}} \delta c_z + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int d^2 z  b_{\bar{z} \bar{z}} \partial_z \delta  c^{\bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int d^2 \partial_{\bar{z}} ( b_{zz}  \delta c_z) - (\partial_{\bar{z}} b_{zz} ) \delta c_z   + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int d^2 z \partial_z ( b_{\bar{z} \bar{z}}  \delta  c^{\bar{z}} ) - \partial_z ( b_{\bar{z} \bar{z}} ) \delta  c^{\bar{z}}   = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int d^2 z \partial_{\bar{z}} ( b_{zz}  \delta c_z) + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int d^2 z \partial_z ( b_{\bar{z} \bar{z}}  \delta  c^{\bar{z}} )  $$

Comment: $$ = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int d z  b_{zz}  \delta c_z| + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int d \bar{z}  b_{\bar{z} \bar{z}}  \delta  c^{\bar{z}}| $$, here $|$ is the upper value subtracts the lower value of integration range. (I only consider variation for $c^z$ and $c^{\bar{z}}$, tehre is a few typos in covariant/concovariant indices) Actually could you provide some derivation steps in your answer?...

Comment: Well, there are still a few flaws, for example that you dropped the non-boundary terms, but nevertheless, what you have in the end are the correct expressions for the boundary terms. Now you just have to convert them to Polchinski's notation by making use of his considerations on tangential and normal vectors.

Comment: Do you mean let $\hat{n}=(-d\bar{z},dz)$ (from http://aesop.phys.utk.edu/strings/str02.pdf p28), (3.3.28) means $d\bar{z}$ comes from $$n^1 b_{11} \delta c^1 + n^1 b_{12} \delta c^2 + \cdots $$. In Euclidean signature, $b_{11}=b^{11},b_{12}=b^{12}$ and from $\sigma^1=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$ and $\sigma^2=\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}$, we (or I ) have $$b^{11}=\frac{1}{4} (b^{zz} + 2 b^{z\bar{z}} + b^{\bar{z} \bar{z}} )$$ and $$b^{12}=\frac{1}{4i} ( b^{zz} -  b^{\bar{z} \bar{z}})$$  , but there is a contribution from $b^{z\bar{z}}$